# What is the reason of defining multiple meanings of a single word?

Tags: ambiguity

For example: the word - "legend" has below two meanings as a noun.

1. a traditional story sometimes popularly regarded as historical but unauthenticated.
2. an extremely famous or notorious person, especially in a particular field.

Why not just have another word for the different meaning. Does it serve any purpose in enriching the language or for user convenience?

Comment: When you invent your new language, you can make sure each word has only one meaning.  English does not have that luxury: its meanings are determined by popuar usage.

Comment: Meaning 2 is not a different meaning. It is the exact same meaning, just applied to a person instead of a thing. You cannot *not* have that happen. You would have to forbid all figures of speech, notably metaphors. The whole point of calling someone a legend, or a star, or cool, or brilliant, is that they are none of these things and both you and them understand that.

Comment: OED Legend has 13 more meanings: 1.A book of readings for use as lessons in church services; 
2.The story of a saint's life
3.A roll, a register, a list. *Obsolete*.
4.In espionage: a false identity that an agent uses in an undercover operation; a cover story.
5.an inscription.
6.The words or letters on either side of a coin or medal. 
7.A caption to an illustration, etc.
8.On a map, diagram, etc., explaining the symbols and abbreviations used.
9.Handwritten characters; *Obsolete. rare*
10 *British Navy*. A written description of a planned ship, 
11.A vast host or multitude; a legion

Comment: It also means explanatory text on a graph or map, and no doubt many other things. What exactly is your point?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about linguistics in general, not English specifically. I doubt it would be on topic on [liguistics.se] either as "why" questions in linguistics generally have the answer "Just because".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you are designing a language from scratch, *and* the purpose of that language is communication of information reliably and efficiently whether in a chaotic or entirely controlled environment then, yes, you totally want strings of base symbols to have a one-to-one map to semantics.

This is an informal way of describing the situation of coding theory, bit transfer over a noisy channel a highly studied engineering discipline.

However, people aren't machines. Or at least not in the engineered way. So things like 'reason' or 'purpose' or 'user experience' are only whispery myths that are only vaguely appear mirage-like to human, natural language.

Which is to say that **human language is not designed at all**. It is not logical, the choices made in outward form are arbitrary (and frankly capricious).

Usually context will differentiate:

> "Don't listen to that old man, he is just a story teller, repeating exaggerated legends."

vs

> "That man made the Kessel run in twelve parsecs, he's a true legend."

Context says one is about a story and the other about a person. Why bother designing an entirely different string for a similar concept when it's really easy to differentiate? If you check your dictionary, *most* words have more than one meaning (usually nearby). In fact I think it is rare that a word has a single meaning. The only place where that happens is in math and science (and even then words often have controversy with multiple ['stipulated' definitions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/)).

Look man, brains aren't computers. There's no code running on that mass of curdled cheese inside your skull. There's no database of words and ther definitions and there's no algorithm that inserts definitions for the words and then compiles to brain-bytecode. Yeah, there totally is electricity or really electrical potential, or really changes in electrical potential from differences in ion pumping between inside and outside over the length of neurons. After that, the information processing model of neurology is a very rough model.

Many of the features of language *look* like they are consciously designed by a very well educated and thoughtful designer but that is just a mirage. It is all unconscious. OK, 'telephone' was made up by that one guy.

None of this is particular to English. All languages have [semantic drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change), metaphorical usages that lead to distinct situations labeled with the same word.